# Aggregate, Transactions and Concurrency in Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

Hope that i can find some help here about certain transaction boundary on an Aggregate.

All the following assumptions were done by using TypeORM and Postgres with a serializable isolation level (i state this only because on how TypeORM manages transaction);

Let's say that i have one Aggregate called Project, and the Project and have any number of Members. Every Member has a role. A project can have only 3 Members with a role of Admin.

Code-wise would be something like this:

```js
class Project {
  private readonly members: Member[] = [];
  addMember(userId: string, role: string) {
    // if role is admin, then checks for the number of admins
    this.members.push(new Member(userId, role));
  }
}
```

So, in order to enforce the invariant, all the members need to be saved at once (let's assume that the number of members is low and therefore we can load it into memory).

Now, let's assume that i have two users editing the project at the same time. The project already has 2 Admins.

Execution 1:

```
const project = projectRepository.getById(projectId);
project.addMember({ userId: "xxx", role: "Admin" });
projectRepository.save(project);
```

Execution 2

```
const project = projectRepository.getById(projectId);
project.addMember({ userId: "yyy", role: "Admin" });
projectRepository.save(project);
```

Both executions will do a transaction like this (using TypeORM):

```sql
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO members (user_id, role) values ('zzz', 'ADMIN');
COMMIT;
```

Both transactions will succeed, therefore the invariant is broken.

Now, it occurs to me that there are a couple of solutions:

#### Solution 1 - Create my own transaction, deleting all the members and adding them again.

This means that whenever a project is saved, all the records from the member table are deleted and inserted again. The invariant will be protected even in distributed environments.

The transaction will be as follows:

```sql
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM members WHERE project_id = 'aaa';
-- Insert statements for the members
COMMIT;
```

#### Solution 2 - Solution 1 is non-sense and this actually works as expected

If this works as expected and solution 1 makes no sense, then there's no transactional boundary.
I could add some distributed lock, but again, there's no transactional boundary, therefore there's no reason for Members to not be an Aggregate of its own. Therefore a counter-measure needs to be set in place every time a member is added to make sure that, if the number of admins is exceeded, it'll be reduced to 3.

Am i missing something here? I'd really appreciate any thoughts on this!

I tried several approaches using TypeORM and the use of transactions, but i guess that this is also theoretical.

Comment: If the isolation level offered is serializable, then transactions are serialized, and the second transaction should see the changes done by the first one, and you can roll it back

Comment: @salil Thanks for commenting. The transactions are not actually serialized, rather the DB makes sure that if the order transactions were exchanged, the output won't be affected, so it's more an enforcement of result than an actual serialization. And as you can see in my example, both INSERT will succeed (already tested this) therefore breaking the invariant.

Comment: If you have a rule that at most 3 users can be admin, then you can't have user be an aggregate root in charge of whether it's an admin.  You can have users be an aggregate (viz. the collection of all users is a single aggregate) or you can have a single admins aggregate responsible for managing which users are admin.

Comment: ...if you're depending on the DB to detect the conflict with serializable transactions, you're effectively putting all the records which could cause a conflict into one aggregate.

Comment: Hey Levi, thanks for your comment. In this case, Project is an Aggregate that has Members (NOT users). A Member has a role, and holds a reference to User Aggregate by its id. And since a Project is the one that cannot have more than 3 members with a Role of ADMIN, it must protect the aggregate, which is done in the example i provided.

Comment: Project having an admin1, admin2, admin3 field would seem to be a natural encoding of this.